# Javascript innerHTML not working with a servlet response

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong with the following code? I am getting a proper response from the servlet, but for some reason cannot get it inside the div. If necessary, the response is:

```
lukas requests to be your friend &nbsp <button value="lukas"onclick="accfr(this.value)">Accept request</button>&nbsp<button value="lukas" onclick="decfr(this.value)">Decline</button><br>
```

Code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Friend panel</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Your requests:<br><br>
    <div id="req"></div>
  </body>

  <script>

    function getreqs(){

      var xmlhttp;

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){  
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ServletTest/DisplayFrRequests", "false");
      xmlhttp.send();
      var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("req").innerHTML=response;
    }

    //var counter = window.setInterval(function(){getreqs()}, 5000);
    getreqs();

    function accfr(){ }
    function decfr(){ }

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to wait for the response. It does not come straight away.

Comment: try appending it to div, if your response consist html tag. yourDiv.append(response);

Comment: Isn't that only done when the request is async="true" ?

Comment: appending does not work

Comment: Why are you passing the async parameter as a string? And why are you using `XMLHttpRequest` for a synchronous call?

Comment: That's it! "false" should not be passed as a string

Comment: Your response is not valid - a few quotes lack escaping.

Answer (score 1):

For an asynchronous call, the parameter true/false should not be in quotes

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ServletTest/DisplayFrRequests", false);
```